# AMD A10-4600M has 2 cores instead 4 problem!

Tags: drivers, cpu, 19.04, multi-core

I have **Ubuntu 19.04**(this problem occurs in 18.04 and 12.04 too), **AMD-4600M** processor.
A `lscpu` command, *settings* and `/proc/cpuinfo` say that my processor has 2 cores, 2 threads, 2048M l2 cache. But I find out that it must have 4 core 4 threads and 4096K.([Official site AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a10-series-apu-for-laptops/a10-4600m-radeon-hd-7660g))

How is it possible?
Am I fool?
Is the driver's problem?
Or something else?

**`lscpu` output:**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          21
Model:               16
Model name:          AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             1443.882
CPU max MHz:         2300.0000
CPU min MHz:         1400.0000
BogoMIPS:            4591.86
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           16K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
```

This is my "Settings screenshot":

[image: Settings screenshot]

And this is my "Official site screenshot":

[image: Official site screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had only one core working (after new install turned always into emergency mode and repaired with fsck).
AMD® Athlon(tm) ii x4 620 processor

To get out the emergency mode (always) I tried many bios changes. I made in the bios (Asus sAM3 M4A785TD-V EVO ver:2015) changes about the power/ **ACPI 2.0 & ACPI APIC**. I made both disabled.
Solution was: made them enabled again. :)